# Android: getString(R.string) in static method

Tags: android, static, getstring

When programming for Android sometimes you have to use static methods. But when you try to access you resources in a static method with `getString(R.string.text)` you'll get an error. Making it static doesn't work.

Does anyone knows a good way around this? The resource files in Android are very helpful for creating things in different languages or making changes to a text.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One way or another, you'll need a Context for that... For static methods this probably means you need to pass along a Context when calling them.

Answer (score 21):

You could use `Resources.getSystem().getStringArray(android.R.array.done);`

Comment: This is a nice solution only the downside is that you can only use system resources.

Comment: @serv-inc - That's not what the `Resources.getSystem()` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getSystem()) says.

Comment: @serv-inc - I mean that according to Google's reference documentation, it doesn't matter if you `import yourpackage.R;` when using `Resources.getSystem().getStringArray()`, because `Resources.getSystem()` returns "a global shared Resources object **that provides access to only system resources**".  Which strongly suggests that @SarenInden is correct and that the follow-up comment will only send people down the wrong path by suggesting they try something that the official documentation explicitly says won't work.

Comment: @aroth: something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/a/41871247/1587329 was meant, but also for subpackages. Thanks for the hint that it could mislead people.

Answer (score 9):

This is how I access resources from inside static methods. Maybe not ideal, but.

First, I extend Application and set some public static field(s), and create a method to initialise them:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

  // static resources
  public static String APP_NAME;

  public static void initResources(Context context) {
    APP_NAME = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
  }
}
```

And in my manifest I register the extended Application:

```
<application 
  android:name=".MyApp"/>
```

In my starter activity (MainActivity), I make a call to initialise the static resources:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  MyApp.initResources(this);   
}
```

Then anywhere in your project, after MainActivity.onCreate(Bundle b) has run, you can call static methods that access your specified static resources:

```
public static void printAppName() {
  Log.w("tag", "my app name: " + MyApp.APP_NAME);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Pass in a `Context` (i.e. `Activity`) instance as a parameter object to static method. Then invoke `getString` on the parameter.

Comment: This CAN be a bad idea. If you're storing references to contexts you could cause a memory leak

Comment: What made you think that I suggest to store a Context reference?

Comment: @Falmarri: you can always use `getApplicationContext()`, which would then valid the whole app lifetime

Comment: ^ wrong.  getApplicationContext() will not work in a static method.

Answer (score 0):

The post below gives a tip for creating an `Application` class to save your current context. Your new `Application` class will then be accessible from any other static method.

> [How can I get a resource content from a static context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391720/android-how-can-i-get-a-resources-object-from-a-static-context)

Answer (score -2):

One way is you can pass context to your static method.
check this out it definitely works

```
public class Sounds {

    public static MediaPlayer getSoundTouch(Context context){
        return MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.touch);

    }

    public static MediaPlayer getSoundLeak(Context context){
        return MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.leak);

    }

    public static MediaPlayer getSoundFinish(Context context){
        return MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.finish);

    }

 }
```