# Strings in strings.xml are causing problems in Android

Tags: java, android

What can I do? I want to offer multilanguage versions, but for this I need every string in strings.xml...with Context.getString it isn't working because of non-static method in static class/method.

[image: Acces to the String]

[image: Can't acces because of int]

Comment: Your first image hasn't loaded? Ignore the R file, that is automatically generated. Show us the compile error in the code :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then do this:

[How can I get a resource content from a static context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391720/android-how-can-i-get-a-resources-object-from-a-static-context/4391811#4391811)

Comment: Thanks, just what I searched!

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see what your trying to do.

The R.string.blah is just an int reference.

To get the actual string you need to do

```
Context.getResources().getString(R.string.blah);
```

[Get String Resource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString%28int%29)

Comment: Ah right didn't see that was what you wanted. Could of always just instantiated your strings in the constructor and passed in the context. Same thing end of the day.