# getting the activity for my app

Tags: android

I've been having some issues reading an XML file in my 'res' folder and I think I've narrowed it down to an issue with my apps 'activity'.

I keep getting a ***NullPointerException*** on line # 2 below.

Here is my code to get the activity.  Is there a better or a right way to do this?

```
1. Activity activity = this;

2. Resources res = activity.getResources();

3. XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.encounters);
```

Here is the class:

```
public class XmlParser extends Activity  {


public XmlParser()
    throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{
    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(false);

        Activity activity = this;
        Resources res = activity.getResources();
        XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.encounters);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        String stackTrace = Log.getStackTraceString(e);
        Log.e("error", stackTrace);
    }
   }
}
```

And I'm getting the error on the "Resources res = activity.getResources();" line...
Thanks!

Comment: I thought this just refers to the app? I'm thinking I'm wrong?

Comment: @999cm999 Unfortunately `this` refers to the instance of the class that the code is currently executing in.  You really need to post more code for us to figure out what's going on.

Comment: chris - ok I edited the main question -- thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something tells me that there's a problem with `this` or `activity` and there's some code missing here.  The code that you've put there shouldn't ever generate a NPE because `this` is never null and if 2 followed 1 immediately, `activity` shouldn't be null.  It's possible that `this` isn't an instance of `Activity` but that would generate a compile error, not an NPE.

**Edit** Ah, I think I see your problem.  You need to override `onCreate()` and this `Activity` will be instantiated by the Android framework.  You then need to move all of the code from the constructor and put it in the `onCreate`() method.  However, I think this is indicative of a fundamental understanding of how applications work in Android.  Instead, what I would do is create a standard Android application in Eclipse.  That will create a base activity for you.  From there, remove the subclassing `Activity` from your `XmlParser` class and change the constructor to take a `Context` argument.  From there, instantiate the `XmlParser` in your other `Activity`, the one that was created by Eclipse.

All of that said, I think you should spend some time reading over the application fundamentals in the developer docs to understand how you're supposed to access resources, etc.

**Edit 2** For more information about `Activities` check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html).  Also, check out [this SO post for how to do what you're trying to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574506/accessing-resources-without-a-context).

Comment: wow, that flew way over my head.  I've been reading through the documentation at 'http://developer.android.com'. Is there anything there that would help explain what you wrote above?  -- thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you run that code inside of a Activity class then you could simply do:

```
Resources res = this.getResources();

XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.encounters);
```