# Is it possible to read a raw text file without Context reference in an Android library project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-resources

I could put a text file in folder res\raw of a library project, but reading it seems to require a Context reference. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503114/android-test-project-reading-assets-file-to-test-plain-java-object/9506449#9506449) to see how to read file from POJO.

Generally, the res folder should be automatically added into project build path by ADT plugin. suppose you have a test.txt stored under res/raw folder, to read it without android.content.Context:

```
String file = "raw/test.txt"; // res/raw/test.txt also work.
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
```

I did this before with an old SDK version, it should work with latest SDK as well. Give it a try and see if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I have just tried.  Eclipse does not like putting a file under res, so I let the file stay in res\raw.  I get null when trying to access the file by this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("text.txt") or this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("raw\text.txt")

Comment: @Hong, I've tried on my Mac with SDK r16 and now I can confirm both "res/raw/test.txt" and "raw/test.txt" works. whereas "test.txt" throws NPE. Note that you need slash (/), not back slash (\\).

Comment: Yes!!! It works!  It works in a static constructor too so that such reading does not have to be carried out every time the method is called. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for testing it. I am also using r16. InputStream in = Myclass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/raw/txt.txt") works, but InputStream in = Myclass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("raw/txt.txt") returns null.

Comment: @Hong, Weird, I've also tried on my Windows box (SDK r16), which also works for both patterns. Are you sure you use **raw/txt.txt**, not with a leading slash **/raw/txt.txt**? As **/raw/txt.txt** throws NPE.

Comment: Yes.  To make sure, I have just tried again with or without the leading slash. This is in a library. Something like MyApp referencing MyClass that is in a library project which has the file txt.txt.

Comment: Oh, this makes sense. I didn't test it from a Library Project, the Library Project classpath is probably altered when get merged/built into Main project. Good point to know.

Comment: This answer worked very well for over 8 years.  A recent Android Studio and its associated components' updates seem to have broken it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67423363/getclassloader-getresourceasstreamfile-path-returns-null-after-android-studi

Answer (score 3):

In order to access a resource you need a context. See here the definition of Context.class from the developer.android site

> Interface to global information about an application environment. This
>   is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android
>   system. It allows access to application-specific resources and
>   classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as
>   launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

So, through a context you can access a resource file. You can create another class and pass the context from an activity to it. Create a method that reads a specified resource file.

For example:

```
public class ReadRawFile {
    //Private Variable
    private Context mContext;

    /**
     * 
     * Default Constructor
     * 
     * @param context activity's context
     */
    public ReadRawFile(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param str input stream used from readRawResource function
     * @param x integer used for reading input stream
     * @param bo output stream
     */
    private void writeBuffer(InputStream str, int x, ByteArrayOutputStream bo){
        //not hitting end
        while(x!=-1){
            //write to output buffer
            bo.write(x);
            try {
                //read next
                x = str.read();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return output file to string
     */
    public String readRawResource(){
        //declare variables
        InputStream rawUniversities = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.universities);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bt = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int universityInteger;

        try{
            //read/write
            universityInteger = rawUniversities.read();
            writeBuffer(rawUniversities, universityInteger, bt);

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //return string format of file
        return bt.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  As my understanding of your answer, there is no way to read a raw text without a Context.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get raw file without context in 2021

```
val Int.rawString: String
    get(){
        var res= ""
        val `is`: InputStream = Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(this)
        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val b = ByteArray(1)
        try {
            while (`is`.read(b) !== -1) {
                baos.write(b)
            }
            res = baos.toString()
            `is`.close()
            baos.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return res
    }
```