# how to read files from assets folder outside of an activity

Tags: java, android, html, search, assets

This is my problem :
Im trying to read a HTML file from asset folder but
i've got this error :

```
 file:/android_asset/Tuberculin.html: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

In my class am extending BaseAdapter

```
public class medic_ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
```

and this is my code :

```
String   path = "file:///android_asset/Tuberculin.html";
   final Scanner scanner= new Scanner(new File(path));
    int i =0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        i++;
         String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();

        if(lineFromFile.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(search)) {
            String a= String.valueOf(i);

            // a match!
            yes=true;
            scanner.close();
            break;
        }

    }

    scanner.close();
```

Is there a way to read asset files without extending activity ?

Comment: You can still use `AssetManager`. Just pass a `Context` into your adapter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android access to resources outside of activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081339/android-access-to-resources-outside-of-activity)