# Kotlin easily access resources outside of an activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new at Android and Kotlin. I'm trying to create a `ResourcesHelper class` to easily access my custom colors and fonts from any other custom class in my app. But in this helper I don't have any context. I've read ways to get the context extending the Application class but then compiler says I can't access this context in my ResourcesHelper companion object as it would create memory leaks. Also I ended up with optional chained.

Here is how I would like to be able to use it :

```
class ResourcesHelper {

    companion object {
        val lightBlue = resources.getColor(R.color.lightBlue)
        val customBlue = resources.getColor(R.color.customBlue)
        // [...]    
        val fontAwesome = resources.getFont(R.font.fontawesome)
        val lemonMilk = resources.getFont(R.font.lemonmilk)
    }
}

enum class ButtonStyle {
    MENU,
    // [...]
    VICTORY
}

class CustomButton(c: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : Button(c, attrs) {

    var isButtonActivated = false

    fun setStyle(style: ButtonStyle) {
        setBackgroundColor(ResourcesHelper.transparent)

        when(style) {
            ButtonStyle.MENU -> {
                setText(R.string.menu_button)
                typeface = ResourcesHelper.lemonMilk
                setBackgroundColor(ResourcesHelper.customRed)
                setTextColor(ResourcesHelper.white)
            }
            // [...]
            ButtonStyle.VICTORY -> {
                setText(R.string.victory_button)
                typeface = ResourcesHelper.lemonMilk
                setBackgroundColor(ResourcesHelper.customRed)
                setTextColor(ResourcesHelper.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also read this post [Android access to resources outside of activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081339/android-access-to-resources-outside-of-activity) but it's in Java and I have no idea on how to do it in Kotlin.

I am completely lost on what and how to do this... Or if there is a better way to achieve reaching resources from anywhere.

Thanks for your help

Comment: *compiler says I can't access this context in my ResourcesHelper companion object as it would create memory leaks* - I think it's a warning, not an error. Also you can ignore it. The application context cannot be leaked

Comment: Thanks ! So I get an optional context. Is it safe do `val myCustomColor = context!!.getColor(R.color.lightBlue)` ? Can my applicationContext be null ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The context you retrieve with your application class is not nullable

Comment: I tried to copy something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445661/how-to-get-the-context-from-anywhere and Android studio converted it in Kotlin and made the context nullable. But I simply can do `val context = Application().applicationContext` directly in my ResourcesHelper this way I have a non nullable context.

Comment: Although if I do like so it crashes the app with a `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
        at com...Common.ResourcesHelper.<clinit>(ResourcesHelper.kt:10)`

Answer (score 4):

For **Color, String, etc system resources** you can use the Resources class, as shown below

```
import android.content.res.Resources

    class ResourcesHelper {
    
        companion object {
            val lightBlue = Resources.getSystem().getColor(R.color.lightBlue)
    
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: `Resources.getColor(id)` is deprecated now

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support different Android versions I'll recommend to use `ContextCompat`. It provides unified interface to access different resources and backward compatibility for older Android versions.

For **AnroidX** use `androidx.core.content.ContextCompat`, for **SupportV4**:  `android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat`.

```
val lightBlue = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.lightBlue)
val customBlue = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.customBlue)
```