# Why is my file not found when using a FileReader in java

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio, filereader

I am trying to find a file I have saved in android studio. I have tried everything: putting the full directory, putting the the file in a new folder in that directory, using `file.getAbsolutePath()`, declaring a file before or putting the file directly into the reader`(BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("history.txt"));`
Here is the code:

```
        File file = new File("Extra Files/history.txt");
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        String scores = r.readLine();
        r.close();
```

No matter what I try it does not seem to work any other ideas, can you not use text files like this in android studio or ???

```
    public void write_score(int ns) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "history.txt");
        BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        w.append(String.valueOf(ns)).append(",");
        w.close();
    }
```

Comment: If you wanna know if a file exists under a certain path then use File.exists().

Comment: Do you get an exception thrown? If so, which one? Or is the `scores`-string just empty?

Comment: `new File("Extra Files/history.txt")` You use a relative path. The File class expects a full path. Please tell your full path.

Comment: use `System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath().toString());` to display the working directory of the java process. Your file is found relative to that.

Comment: @itzFlubby I got a FileNotFoundException exception

Comment: @blackapps I tried the full file path and it didn't work, ```file.exists()``` comes back as false so what can I do from there

Comment: The file isn't where you said it was, relative to the current working directory when you executed the code . You don't need the absolute or canonical path here. [tag:BufferedReader] has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to read from the file, you could put it in the assets or res/raw folder and read from them using `context.getAssets().open("filename") or context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.resourceName)` to get the input streams and then using `BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileStream))` to get the reader . If not, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10081539/13326385), should have the answer to let you to read from a different folder.

If you want to write to it, though, one way is to use the [app-specific internal files](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific) which can be accessed with

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
```

But you will first need to create the history.txt file using `file.createNewFile()` and fill it with whatever you wanted because it won't already exist the first time you try to access it. After that it should be fine though. I hope this helps.

Edit:

Here is some sample code to read/write to the internal file

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);//Or use Log.d(line);
        }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and

```
 public void write_score(int ns) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "history.txt");
    BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));//true makes it append
    w.write(String.valueOf(ns) + ",");
    w.close();
}
```

Comment: When you say res/raw folder, is that res or raw folder or the raw folder in the res folder as I don't have a raw folder.

Comment: I meant the raw folder in the res folder. If you don't have one you can just create it either in android studio or use and external file navigator and create the folder through that (I think I just used windows explorer to create mine).

Comment: I tried the first method ```context.getAssets().open("filename")``` gut that didn't work, when I try the second method it says it has to be an integer, any idea what I have to put there?

Comment: You need to put the R.raw.name ID in as the input integer with name being whatever the name of the file is without the extension.

Comment: So that worked however, the when I read from it it gives me a NullPointerException, sorry to be a pain, any ideas?

Comment: Just wondering, does the file have anything in it? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: It didn't but I wrote some random stuff in it and I got the same exception thrown

Comment: Could you try something real quick and tell me what the value of context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.resourceName).availible() is? with resourceName, of course, being whatever the name of the file is

Comment: Oh sorry but I just realised its another error and it does work, and available() is 1. Sorry

Comment: Just a quick question, other than writing some random stuff in the file to make it not null, is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Also, I have just tried to write something using the other method, luckily it doesn't give me an error however it doesn't write anything to the file, any ideas there? Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: Well for the first question, you could check using the .availible method on the inputstream or the .length method on the file to see if there are any bytes availible to read, if not (if it returns a 0) then you can just skip reading from the file until writing because nothing is there to be read (This isn't a surefire way but it is better than nothing). As for the second question, (if I understand correctly you are using the .getFilesDir() file right?) the changes wont appear in android studio because they are only made on the phone which ran the program and can only be viewed by the app

Comment: Ok that makes sense, should I be able to see it change using ```System.out.println(fileContents)```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if System.out works on all of the physical devices, but it is worth a try. If not then Android's Log class e.g. Log.d(fileContents) should do the same thing.

Comment: Well I tried both methods and obviously looked at the output on my actual device however when I try to write something it only writes the current thing and not the previous stuff also. I am first reading the file using a bufferedreader and then writing that + new data to the file, any ideas?

Comment: I added the code to my question, I still can't get it to work though.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I forgot how the .append() worked on the BufferedWriter, it won't do what I said it would. Instead when you make the BufferedWriter instance do it like this: new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)) the true will make the .write method append to the file

Comment: I added the code and added lots of Log statements but it still won't write to the file.