# Android - Issue dealing with static method (?) and the last step

Tags: android

This is really doing my head in, I have been following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391720/android-how-can-i-get-a-resources-object-from-a-static-context/4391811#4391811) instructions but it won't work.  Step three is causing me trouble.  I'm note sure exactly what needs to be added where. It says;

> "In the onCreate() method of your app instance, save your context (e.g. this) to a static >field named app and create a static method that returns this field, e.g. getApp():"

But I only have this at the top of my main java file:

```
   protected static final String App = null;
```

The error I get is on this line, it says "The method getContext() is undefined for the type String":

```
   String[] items = App.getContext().getResources().getStringArray(testholderint);
```

I figure the issues is with not following step three, and was wondering what exactly I need to add.

Once I've got this rectified my project is basically finished...

Comment: Still could not understand your question, try replacing `String App;` to `Application app;`

Answer (score 0):

I think this line

```
protected static final String App = null;
```

shouldn't appear at all. The link you provided tells you to create a subclass of your application, like

```
public class App extends Application { ... }
```

In this subclass you should put the onCreate() and getContext() methods indicated in the code provided at that link. After doing so your last line (String[] items...) should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I realise one stupid mistake I think I was making.  I also deleted the line that you suggested but the program still crashes for no apparent reason.

Comment: Let's see... I'm concerned with that "testholderint". If, as I think, you're trying to retrieve a "StringArray" resource, you need to refer to it as "R.array.testholderint". But maybe you already did it and stored the value in the "testholderint" variable, so I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Anyway, it would help to see the manifest and the App class to check if everything is as it should be.