# context.getResources().openRawResource() crashes the app

Tags: android, file, text, android-resources, android-context

I'm trying for a while to make android read from a text file that I already have in the R.raw folder.

I have the function void readfile(Context context) that contains the line

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
```

However when I try to run the app it crashes at that exact line. Can you tell me a workaround? Or another way to read from that file?

Comment: may be `context is null....add your logcat`

Answer (score 1):

There is obviously a problem with the given context. You should post your logcat.

There is 2 ways to solve your problem.

1. Pass a correct context: see what is wrong with your program and why the given context is not correct.
2. Extend Application, and save the application context in a static variable: see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391720/android-how-can-i-get-a-resources-object-from-a-static-context)

Comment: Of course! I'm sorry. Here's the logcat report after pasting your line of code instead of mine: `W/dalvikvm(279): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)`

Comment: And by the way, Context should be lowercased, as getApplicationContext isn't static(according to my compiler) and that's a static reference right there.

Comment: Well this time I get another error, although on debugging the crash method is quite the same: it crashes at the same line after opening the ZygoteInit$MethodAnd file(which hasn't any content). The  error is ` E/AndroidRuntime(289): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.localhost/com.localhost.ShapesActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040000`

Comment: @user1489886 Ok I thought it was possible to get resources without a context, I will edit my post.