# Android getting resources in fragments from static context

Tags: java, android, static, resources

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391720/android-how-can-i-get-a-resources-object-from-a-static-context) to try and solve my problem. It is similar but I use fragments so when I need context I usually need to call getActivity().

Basically I have App.java as described in the link above, I have

```
android:name=".App" inside my <application> tag
```

added to my AndroidManifest.xml. Now I have this class I use to collect all the things i use frequently:

```
public class MiscMethods{
public static void ErrorToast(int errorCode) {
    String errorString = null;
    if(errorCode==1){ errorString = App.getContext().getString(R.string.error_tooManyFieldsEmpty);}
    if(errorCode==2){ errorString = App.getContext().getString(R.string.error_featureComingSoon);}
    if(errorCode==3){ errorString = App.getContext().getString(R.string.error_SwitchBreak);}
    else{errorString="Wrong Error Code";}
    Toast errormsg = Toast.makeText(App.getContext(), errorString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    errormsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    errormsg.show();
}
}
```

In one of my fragments I call

```
MiscMethods.ErrorToast(1);
```

I just get the "Wrong Error Code" message from the "else {}" part of my  method

Can you help me make this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better formatting would have made your issue easier to find:

```
public static void ErrorToast(int errorCode) {
    String errorString = null;
    if (errorCode == 1) {
        errorString = App.getContext().getString(R.string.error_tooManyFieldsEmpty);
    }
    if (errorCode == 2) {
        errorString = App.getContext().getString(R.string.error_featureComingSoon);
    }
    if (errorCode == 3) {
        errorString = App.getContext().getString(R.string.error_SwitchBreak);
    } else {
        errorString = "Wrong Error Code";
    }
    Toast errormsg = Toast.makeText(App.getContext(), errorString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    errormsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    errormsg.show();
}
```

As you might now see is that your `if (errorCode == 1)` should work but will be overridden as `if (errorCode == 3)` will be false in this case and your else will override your `errorString` variable.

A `switch(errorCode)` and the 3 cases are what you are looking for.

Final tip: improve your formatting!

Comment: Thanks, wasn't a formatting issue, i just didn't understand that the else goes as soon as the last before it is false... i thought it only goes if all of the above are false :) made a switch now

Comment: I just meant that with a better formatting, you should have seen the program flow easier :) You read the code 10 times more than you write, so good readability is always worth the "more work".

Answer (score 0):

write under code in Your **CoreApplication.java**

[step1]

```
public class CoreApplication extends Application {

private static CoreApplication instance; 
}
```

[step2]

```
onCreate(){
instance = this;
}
```

[step3]
add

```
public static CoreApplication getGlobalApplicationContext() {

if (instance == null) {
throw new IllegalStateException("this application does not 
inherit GlobalApplication"); " +
"}

return instance;
}
```

[Step4]
Call `getGlobalApplicationContext()` in your fragment