# How to get Width and height of item in the drawable?

Tags: android, view, ondraw

I am trying to declare and initialize a variable globally as `final`, this variable should holde the`width` and the `height` of an element in the `drawable`, how to achieve that.
I want smothing like the followinf "ofcourse it is not working, but it is roughly what i am trying to achieve:

`private final int w = R.drawable.element.getwidth`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/android-get-width-returns-0

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "element in the drawable". Could you elaborate?

Comment: @XaverKapeller I have 52 graphical element in the drawable, all of the same width and height. I want to declare a variable that hold the height and width of  a single card

Comment: Could you show us the `drawable` you are talking about? You can use ids to get a specific `drawable` from a composed `drawable`.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I appreciate your attempt to help. but i know how to reference the drawable by ids, but how to get the width of and item in the drawable

Comment: Are you just generally asking how to get the size of a `drawable`? Or is there something else. I should tell you that your question doesn't really make sense, by definition you have to tell a drawable how big it should be. They do not have a defined size.

Comment: @XaverKapeller the drawable has 52 element. how to the width and height of a single element in the drawable?

Comment: What kind of elements are you talking about? You have to tell me what kind of `Drawable` you are using and what kind of elements are in there. But again as I have told you: `Drawables` have no size. They just represent something that can be drawn. You tell the drawable how big it should be and it will draw itself that way. You can call `getIntrinsicHeight()` or `getIntrinsicWidth()`, but you shouldn't think of the values returned by those two methods as width and height of the `Drawable`, because as I already told you: a `Drawable` has no predefined size.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function `getDrawableWidth`

```
private int getDrawableWidth(Resources resources, int id){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, id);
    return bitmap.getWidth();
}
```

Then call it as below:

```
private final int w = getDrawableWidth(getResources(), R.drawable.element)
```

===Edit===

define a class to get global context([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4391811/1029127)):

```
public class App extends Application{

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

then change `getDrawableWidth` to another format:

```
private int getDrawableWidth(int id){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(App.getContext().getResources(), id);
    return bitmap.getWidth();
}
```

use it any where:

```
private final int w = getDrawableWidth(R.drawable.element)
```

Comment: but i want to define that variable `W` globally!