# values are set to null after onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, listview, simpleadapter, onactivityresult

I have a `DialogFragment` class with a custom xml layout. 
In  onCreateView() I get reference to a button. You click it to choose file.
When it's clicked two things happen:
1) It uses a layout inflater to add another xml layout into the current one
2) It initializes three variables to their values `ListView`, `ListArray`, `SimpleAdapter`, and these are member variables declared at the top of the class.
3) Then it calls `getActivity().startActivityForResult()`

Problem: The three variables described above are set to null when I come back into this activity to the dialogfragment.

---

---

Here is a detailed version of what's happening:

```
//before calling startActivityForResult()
I/NULLTEST SIMPLEADAPTER﹕ android.widget.SimpleAdapter@64cf1348
I/NULLTEST ATTACHMENTSLISTVIEW﹕ android.widget.ListView{64d1c2e0 VFED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090014 app:id/attachmentsListView}
I/NULLTEST ATTACHMENTSLISTARRAY﹕ [{a_date_added=Added: Nov 1, a_name=My test file 0}, {a_date_added=Added: Nov 2, a_name=My test file 1}, {a_date_added=Added: Nov 3, a_name=My test file 2}]
// Inside onActivityResult()
I/NULLTEST SIMPLEADAPTER ONRESULT﹕ null
I/NULLTEST ATTACHMENTSLISTVIEW ONRESULT﹕ null
I/NULLTEST ATTACHMENTSLISTARRAY ONRESULT﹕ []
```

This whole code is being called inside a `DialogFragment`. As you can see above before calling `startActivityForResult()` the three variables `SimpleAdapter`, `ListView`, and `ArrayList` are set to some value. They are all member variables thus can be called anywhere in this class.
Inside `onCreateView()` method of `DialogFragment` I get reference to a button part of the dialog and attach a `setOnClickListener()` to the button. When this button is clicked, the three variables described above are initialized to their values and I use `Log.i` to log the values. The button `onClick()` also calls the `getActivity().startActivityForResult();` to allow me to choose a file thus opening a completely different `Activity`. I choose the file and the `onActivityResult()` method of the host `Activity` is called which for my case is `MainActivity.java`. From here the data is passed onto the `DialogFragment` as such:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
```

Now I have access to the data inside the `DialogFragment` but in the `onActivityResult` of the `DialogFragment` not the `Activity`, the three variables described above are set to null but they are only initialized on the button click but that would call `startActivityForResult()` and so on. I do not understand why they are set back to null. Am I missing something important here? Due to this I cannot call for example `simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. This exact way of updating my listview works if I do this in an `Activity` instead of a `DialogFragment` but I need to do this inside a `DialogFragment`. Also any other ways of updating listview after retrieving data from another activity are welcome. I just need a way to update that listview when I select more data.

**FINAL UPDATE**

I would like to apologize to for the height of stupidity that I was making. In my hosting `Activity` which is `MainActivity.java`, when this `Activity` would call `onActivityResult()` I would create a new instance of the dialog fragment as such: `new MyDialogFragment().onActivityResult()` and obviously this is why none of your guys methods worked as `onCreateView` wasn't called this time. I have change `new MyDialogFragment()` to the previously initialized dialog fragment that I am actually displaying and everything works now. And I will close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the request code is the correct code fro request. You may requesting another code

Comment: it is correct. the data I recieve in onActivityResult is correct.

Comment: also calling something such as this works `iv.setImageURI(data.getData());` and the `iv` is created the exact same way. `iv = ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

When you start your activity before that try to use this.

```
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

Comment: @someguy234 Have you found any solution to this ?