# Can not get strings from string.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, string

**Solved with this answer [How can I get a resource content from a static context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391720/how-can-i-get-a-resource-content-from-a-static-context/4391811#4391811)**

Today I decided that my app should be available in different languages so I changed every normal string like...:

```
String hw = "hello world";
```

..to:

```
XML:

<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
App:

String hw= getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);
```

But for some reason it doesn't show the text anymore. Everthing worked fine when I used the normal methode but now it doesn't. I tried getText() too but this doesn't work neither. I am using the strings to get them into an ArrayList like this:

```
public  hello(){

    meineListe.add(hello_world);
```

Complete class:

```
public class favorites extends Activity {

static int x = -1;

private ArrayList<String> meineListe = new ArrayList<String>();

public  favorites(){
    String a1 = getResources().getString(R.string.a1);
    String aa1 = getResources().getString(R.string.aa1);
    String aaa1 = getResources().getString(R.string.aaa1);
```

Comment: *"I tried getText() too"* tried using that how? Did you use a log or breakpoint to see what `hw` is?

Comment: String hw = (String) getText(R.string.hello_world);

Answer (score 1):

Try - `meineListe.add(getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world));`
and make sure that you declared strings in res/values/strings.xml file.

Comment: tried it but doesn't work too

Comment: This is what the OP is doing already. Just trying to add it to a String variable before adding to the list

Comment: @Silas i edited my code recheck it.

Comment: Still doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: @Silas What is problem in code? data is null or any exception?

Comment: I am using the array list to change a textview everytime someone presses a button. This worked when I used the strings normal but if i use them like this then i press the button but nothing happens

Comment: @Silas can you please add your full code to add data in array.

Comment: This basically is my full code to add it into the array. There are just more strings but this is how im adding it.

Comment: @Silas Make sure R is not android.R it should be your_package.R in imports.

Comment: still doesn't work. I edited my question to show the complete adding. Do I need to make the getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world) in the MainActivity? Because this isn't my MainActivity I just extended Activity. Does this make any difference and if so is there a way to still use it not in the main acitivity?

Comment: I actually managed to let it work now. You were a pretty big help and brought me in the right direction. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so,the point is that you need the context of your main activity.

I am not sure where you call that getResources().getString bla bla, but,it goes like this:

CASE 1: You call it in your main activity.

If this is the case,you do this:

```
 String hw= this.getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);
```

CASE2: You call it in some other class/activity/fragment?

Step1: In your main activity you add this code:

```
 Context context = this;
```

Step2: You pass the context to whatever class you want and you use it like you used "this" in your main activity.

```
 Context context;
 //
 //Code,variables,whatever you got there
 //

 //In your constructor, or method which you used to pass the context from main activity:

 context.this = context;
 String hw= context.getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);
```

This should do the trick.