# How to use getString(R.string) in an external class?

Tags: android

I would like to know how to obtain the value from a string `getString(R.string)` in an external class.

Comment: This site accepts questions in English only.

Comment: These sites are places where you can ask or answer Android application development questions in Spanish: http://www.andglobe.com/#es. (Google Translate: Estos sitios son lugares donde se puede hacer o contestar preguntas de desarrollo de aplicaciones para Android en español: http://www.andglobe.com/#es)

Comment: The most obvious way is to pass context to this class constructor initializer.  You can declare global context in application extending class and make it static but it's not the most elegant way

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391720/how-can-i-get-a-resource-content-from-a-static-context/4391811#4391811 This is the best solution, in my opinion. --- But you can also do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8765789/8312196

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

Java Code:

```
String string = getString(R.string.hello);
```

strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello!</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: That can only be done within the activity, what I need it is to get strings.xml values in an external class activity.

Comment: Do you mean a class that doesn't extend anything? I'm not really sure what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
public static class OtherClass{

    public static void getString(Context mContext){
        String str = mContext.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Log.i("String value", str);
    }

}
```

How to call from **Activity**:

```
OtherClass.getString(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need context to use `getString(..)` method in any class.

Make one MyApplication.java class file.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Add `name` argument in `Application` tag in manifest file like,

```
<application
   android:name=".MyApplication"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   ....
```

And then in you any class you can use below line to use `getString(..)` method.

```
String string = MyApplication.getContext().getString(...);
```