# Set image bitmap from static non-activity class

Tags: android, bitmap, static, android-drawable, android-context

I am working on adding achievement to an `app`. I have a global achievements controller that is in charge of updating and setting achievements to complete. I want to assign a bitmap to each achievement, that will be displayed when the achievement has been completed.

I am trying to do the follow in the `AchievementController`:

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.someImage);
Achievement.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

But the method `getresources` will not work, because there is no context.

I cannot pass the context as a parameter to this class, because it is static.

So, I need some way to set bitmaps in a static class, without using a context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static way to get 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)

Comment: those answers all use weird hacks to get a context, and they admittedly don't guarantee that they'll even be called in time. I'd rather use some way to get a bitmap without having to use a context at all, which is what my question is asking for.

Comment: If you want to use system resources you need to use like `Resources.getSystem().getString(android.R.string.cancel)` or else you should pass context to it. If you want local resources see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4391811/2462531)

Comment: so, there is no good way to simply assign a bitmap to a class object, without using some weird workaround to pass context?

Comment: Yes, as the name suggests, it's the context of current state of the application/object.