# How to access android string resource from another class / static context?

Tags: android, string, multilingual, android-resources

Note that I have already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391720/how-can-i-get-a-resource-content-from-a-static-context) solution and it **does not work** for me .
I have a class of this structure :

```
public class TutorialSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
    private Context context;
    List<String>  instructions = new ArrayList<>();
    public TutorialSwipeAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        addInstructions();    

    }
    //Other code
    private void addInstructions() {       
instructions.add(App.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.Instructions_part1)); // STRING OBJECT TO BE ACCESSED 
}
}
```

Now, the solution works fine in general scenarios , it is rendering the default string resource as expected. But when I **change the language** ,it still renders the default resource (here English) whereas I want the text in Hindi . All the other string resources get converted as expected so there is no issue with the *Locale* class.  How do I solve this issue?

**UPDATE** : I used `context.getString(...)` and changed the context ( removed null pointer exception ) and it works fine now. Thanks @[Khemraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6891563/khemraj) for the comments.

Comment: You can directly access resources via `context.getString(...)` here

Comment: It gives me a null pointer exception when i use  `context.getString(...)`    _java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getString(int)' on a null object reference_

Comment: Your context is null, you need to pass context from the place your are calling this adapter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! It works fine now , thanks a ton !