# how to change value of string in android studio to get it as global variable

Tags: android, xml

I need to put value of strings.xml from android java class to get it from all the application activity

```
<resource>
     <string name="x">sss</string>
</resource>
```

Comment: Can you explain your question properly?

Comment: take static variable and use where you want to access this variable

Comment: Check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391720/how-can-i-get-a-resource-content-from-a-static-context/4391811#4391811

Answer (score 0):

This task is can't be done when using android because the xml strings it's final file compiled when running the application