# Error:(64, 72) error: non-static method getString(int)

Tags: java, android

What's wrong? 
I am trying to extract a string used in strings.xml 
but I get error:

```
Error:(64, 72) error: non-static method getString(int) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Code:

```
private static String file_url  = "http://xxxx.yy/" + getString(R.string.next_update_id);
```

Comment: Where is your "getString" method?

Comment: <string name="next_update_id">xxxxx</string> is from strings.xml

Comment: Opps, forgot it was Android.

Comment: no problem, Thanks for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: getString(R.string) in static method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822732/android-getstringr-string-in-static-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message that you are receiving is already the answer: [`getString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)) is a non-static method and you are trying to use it in a static context. Here "static context" means defining a static variable.

```
private static String file_url
```

You could solve this issue by removing the static modifier from your member declaration.

Answer (score 4):

Create class MyApplication that extends Application. Implement singleton:

```
private static MyApplication instance;

public static MyApplication getInstance() {
     return instance;
}

public void onCreate() {
        instance = this;
}
```

Then use `MyApplication.getInstance().getString(R.string.next_update_id)`

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Error again.  error: non-static method getResources(int) cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix

```
    private static String file_url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Add only this
        file_url = "http://xxxx.yy/" + getString(R.string.next_update_id);
}
```

Comment: @cricket_007 Not wrong with the current accepted answer. I extended it. Add how simple fix it.