# ArrayList with getString from Static Class

Tags: java, android

I have a class like this :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/*  Get ArrayList  of UserModel type  */
public class GetUserModelData {
    public static ArrayList<UserModel> getUserModelData() {
        ArrayList<UserModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add(new UserModel("Droid", "droid@gmail.com"));
        arrayList.add(new UserModel("John", "john@gmail.com"));
        arrayList.add(new UserModel("David" , "david@gmail.com"));
        arrayList.add(new UserModel("Humpy", "humpy@gmail.com"));
        arrayList.add(new UserModel("Sharma", "sharma@gmail.com"));
        arrayList.add(new UserModel("Dravid", "dravid@gmail.com"));
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

I want use getString instead hardcode text. Because this ArrayList dataset is use for multiple Fragment.

Can anyone helpme.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to use getString under UserModel

Comment: @MuhammadAlRidha It is very unclear of what you're trying to achieve. getString would imply that you want to retrieve a hardcoded string, yet your question suggest you want you use that instead of hardcoded text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: getString(R.string) in static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822732/android-getstringr-string-in-static-method)

Comment: Hii Ryan, i already try that. It can't work either.

Comment: @GarrenFitzenreiter `arrayList.add(new UserModel(getString(R.string.driod), getString(R.string.driod_email)));` i want to achieve like this. Inside this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use getString instead of hard-coded text in a separate class, you need to pass Context as a parameter like this:

```
public static ArrayList<UserModel> getUserModelData(Context context) {
}
```

then use it like that:

```
arrayList.add(new UserModel(context.getResources().getString(R.string.droidName), context.getResources().getString(R.string.droidEmail)));
```

Do not forget to put your texts in **strings.xml** file

```
 <string name="droidName">Droid</string>
 <string name="droidEmail">droid@gmail.com</string>
```

Comment: Thanks your advise above work perfectly in my case.

Comment: I'm glad that I helped you. You are most welcome.